# How to find a facebook page associated with a domain name?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

So the problem is simple but I am unable to figure out how to find a fb Page or fb page ID associated with a domain name. 
I have domain name and got domainId by fql or graph api domain object.
No how to find the page ID associted!

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanx

Comment: I don’t think there is any way to find that connection.

Comment: Well, I checked a website called woorank.com, surprisingly they are able to do it! How are they able to do it then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! A simple way could be using wildcard in google advance search.

Try searching on google :

vocabmonk.com inurl:https://www.facebook.com/*/info

NOTE : Here you will have to assume that the first result is original fb page of that domain & they have mentioned the domain on "info" page of your facebook page(Which is pretty obvious 99% of the time).

Let us know if this works for you.